# RequireJs - option to trap errors

Tags: requirejs

I have a lot of RequireJs callbacks like the following:

```
require(['module1', 'module2'], function(Module1, Module2) {
    Module1.doSomething();
    Module2.doSomethingElse();
    moreStuff();
});
```

I'd like to be able to debug errors in those inner methods, directly by having my browser's debugger break on uncaught exceptions. The problem is that these exceptions are always caught, because RequireJS itself catches them and then routes them into the errback stuff. Is there a way to make it not do that?

Comment: It is untrue that RequireJS catches all exceptions that happens in callbacks passed to it. If you run `require(["require"], function () { throw new Error("something"); })` the `Error` will trickle up the stack and be detected as an unhandled exception. Since this is the default behavior, it is unclear what it is exactly you are trying to work around.

Comment: Thanks. With that hint, I found the problem. It is true that RequireJS catches exceptions - if you've set the onError function to something custom, which I had.